# Correct BOOST_FOREACH usage?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach

When using `BOOST_FOREACH`, is the following code safe?

```
BOOST_FOREACH (const std::string& str, getStrings())
{
  ...
}

...

std::vector<std::string> getStrings()
{
  std::vector<std::string> strings;
  strings.push_back("Foo");
  ...
  return strings;
}
```

Or should I grab a copy of the container *before* calling `BOOST_FOREACH`, e.g.:

```
const std::vector<std::string> strings = getString();
BOOST_FOREACH (const std::string& str, strings)
{
  ...
}
```

In the first example is there any danger that `BOOST_FOREACH` could end up calling `getStrings()` multiple times?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> And although BOOST_FOREACH is a macro,
>   it is a remarkably well-behaved one.
>   It evaluates its arguments exactly
>   once, leading to no nasty surprises

Comment: It's a quote from their documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BOOST_FOREACH` whenever you want to traverse things, in a concise manner. Consider Boost.Range to traverse your own classes with BOOST_FOREACH.

I use `BOOST_FOREACH` to prevent pollution of code with `for` statements, iterators ( declaration initilization, etc...)
I use STL algorithms (cogweels) with boost lambda expressions (the glue) as much I can. It makes the code more much understandable than a custom for loop.