# BOOST_FOREACH Iteration over boost::shared_ptr<list>

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, temporaries, boost-foreach

I'm doing something similar to this item [Correct BOOST_FOREACH usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271907/correct-boost-foreach-usage)

However, my returned list is wrapped in a boost::shared_ptr.  If I do not assign the list to a variable before the BOOST_FOREACH loop, I get a crash at runtime as the list is getting destructed as it is a temporary.

```
boost::shared_ptr< list<int> > GetList()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< list<int> > myList( new list<int>() );
    myList->push_back( 3 );
    myList->push_back( 4 );
    return myList;
}
```

Then later..

```
// Works if I comment out the next line and iterate over myList instead
// boost::shared_ptr< list<int> > myList = GetList();

BOOST_FOREACH( int i, *GetList() ) // Otherwise crashes here
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

I would like to be able to use the above without having to introduce a variable 'myList'.
Is this possible?

Comment: How does it crash? With any assertion fail? Or something else?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00426692 in BOOSTFOREACH.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee.

Comment: I'm assuming the crash is because the list<int> has been destroyed (I traced through the destructor) but BOOST_FOREACH craps out when trying to call list<int>::begin()

Comment: You're dereferencing the shared_ptr but never copying it to a new shared_ptr so the reference count will reach 0 and it will be destroyed.  If you were to try doing auto list = GetList(); on the line before and then BOOST_FOREACH( int i, *list ) it should fix that specific error.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's something I'll need to do in the end.  I started using BOOST_FOREACH to avoid having to do all this in the first place.

Comment: Returning the shared_ptr  by value causes the copy constructor to run, which will increment the internal object count. This should take care of preserving the list.

Comment: The shared_ptr is being returned by value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the 'Best Practice' for shared_ptr mentions to avoid using unnamed temporaries:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices

> Avoid using unnamed shared_ptr
> temporaries to save typing; to see why
> this is dangerous, consider this
> example:

```
void f(shared_ptr<int>, int); int g();

void ok() {
    shared_ptr<int> p(new int(2));
    f(p, g()); }

void bad() {
    f(shared_ptr<int>(new int(2)), g()); }
```

> The function ok follows the guideline
> to the letter, whereas bad constructs
> the temporary shared_ptr in place,
> admitting the possibility of a memory
> leak. Since function arguments are
> evaluated in unspecified order, it is
> possible for new int(2) to be
> evaluated first, g() second, and we
> may never get to the shared_ptr
> constructor if g throws an exception.
>
> The exception safety problem described above may also be eliminated by using the make_shared or allocate_shared factory functions defined in boost/make_shared.hpp. These factory functions also provide an efficiency benefit by consolidating allocations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::get()
```

Example:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( int i, static_cast< list<int> >( *(GetList().get()) ) ) {

}
```

The problem is that you can't dereference a boost::shared_ptr and hope it returns the underlying object it stores. If this was true, then there would be no way to dereference a pointer to a boost::shared_ptr. You need to use the specialized ::get() method to return the object stored by boost::shared_ptr, and then dereference that.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#get for the documentation.

Comment: “If this was true, then there would be no way to dereference a pointer to a boost::shared_ptr.” That sounds wrong. There is no logical connection between these two assertions, and in fact it’s at least partially wrong: [Dereferencing a `shared_ptr` *does* return the underlying object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#indirection).

Comment: I no longer get the crash with the line you suggested above.  Out of curiosity, I tried BOOST_FOREACH( int i, static_cast< list<int> >(*GetList()) ) as well, which worked, but it's unclear to me why.

Comment: If I were to guess it's the static_cast is forcing a copy of the list whereas just the *GetList is using a reference to a now destroyed list (because the shared_ptr is destroyed).

Comment: Perhaps its nonsense hidden within the FOR_EACH macro that's causing the problems.

Comment: the static_cast<> is indeed causing the list copy ctor to be called, which I'm trying to avoid have happen in the first place by passing smart pointers around instead of copies of lists

Comment: you could try this to verify: *static_cast< list<int> * >( GetList().get() )
that is, dereference after the cast instead of before. this would prohibit the copy constructor from running since you are casting be reference now, rather than by value.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too, but it resulted in the crashing behavior, that is the list gets destructed before BOOST_FOREACH calls begin() on it.